# other commands executed failed after JMeter command-line

Tags: jmeter, command

execute JMeter test in command-line and deal with the output files

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l output.jtl
copy output.jtl output_A.jtl
```

after execute this file, I find that the 2nd line `copy...` is not executed.
Actually, `jmeter` will be executed for a while, and the subsequent lines may be ignored.

Now I put `jmeter` in another file and call it from the main command file. Can I put them into one file?
How can I deal with such situation?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add `&&` between your commands like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l output.jtl && copy output.jtl output_A.jtl
```

More information: [Using multiple commands and conditional processing symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490954(v=technet.10)#using-multiple-commands-and-conditional-processing-symbols)

Comment: It should make sense. I've tried it but it fails on my side. Thanks any way -> a new thinking